# UWP Application not launching from debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, monogame

I've got a UWP app (MonoGame based game). When I attempt to debug, the application builds, deploys and then fails to launch. I can manually start the app, and then the debugging session continues normally.

There are no error messages, Visual studio just stops, waiting for my app to begin.

This occurs with local sessions, and also remote sessions.

I've uninstalled my app, rebuilt it, and changed it's association with the store. This behavior occurred when I switched from a local debugging session, and then back to a local one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schumi1331 was right. See my screenshot to check if you have enabled this option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like if you have enabled the "Do not launch but debug my code when it starts" option available in the Project Properties (right click on your Project, then open Properties at the bottom and select Debug in the left sidebar).